# Naruto shippuden episodes

Tags: naruto

Are there any dubbed episodes of Naruto Shippuden after episode 388? And if so are they continuing dubbing episodes?

I have looked everywhere and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the dubs are [lagging a bit behind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Naruto:_Shippuden_episodes#DVD_releases) the subs, which is to be expected.  Given the rate of release, you can expect another handful of these dubs to be released every three or so months.

Comment: Sad... It's painful trying to read the subtitles while watching the stuff...